# How can I select keys from a hash in Ruby with a string of javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, rubygems, hash

I'm working on a command line tool in Ruby which parses JSON from various sources and does some work with the data. I want the user to be able to use the tool with any JSON source, so the gem reads some basic configuration from a YAML file provided by the user like this:

```
# config.yml

json_sources:
  sourcea:
    url: 'https://example.com/some/json/api.json'
    list_key: 'response.items'
    name_key: 'name'
  sourceb:
    url: 'https://otherexample.org/another/api.json'
    list_key: ''
    name_key: 'basics.name'
```

In this example, the JSON returned from `https://example.com/some/json/api.json` would look something like this:

```
{
  "response": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": 'Item 1'
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": 'Item 2'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the JSON from `https://otherexample.org/another/api.json` would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "basics": {
      "name": "Other Item 1"
    }
  },
  {
    "basics": {
      "name": "Other Item 2"
    }
  }
]
```

In each case, `url` is the URI for the JSON, `list_key` is the key that should be iterated over in the JSON, and `name_key` is the key we want to fetch from each object. **So, my question is, in Ruby, how should I parse `list_key` and `name_key`?**

Is there some handy way in Ruby to fetch the value of a key in a hash with a string of javascript style selectors or should I just write a method for it myself?

Answer (score 0):

The standard ruby JSON library?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

Comment: I'm already using the JSON library to parse the JSON. I need to know how to fetch a key from the resulting hash using a string of javascript like this `some.deeply.nested.key`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I like most about Javascript is the way you can access the properties of an object with `object.property` as well as `object["property"]`. In Ruby you can only access the value of a hash with `hash["value"]`.

To answer your question, you will need to find a way of converting `list_key` and `name_key` so that it works in Ruby. The best way to do that depends on how you're handling the parsing of the JSON in the first place but I it should be as simple as splitting `list_key` and `name_key` up into an array of stings and then accessing those values on the hash.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one had a better answer yet, I just went ahead and wrote a method:

```
def get_value_from_selector(hash, selector_string)
  selectors = selector_string.split '.'
  selectors.each do |selector|
    hash = hash[selector] if hash
  end
  hash
end
```

I call it like this:

```
raw_json_string = '{ "response": { "name": "foo" } }'
json = JSON.parse raw_json_string
x = get_value_from_selector json, 'response.name'
```

This sets `x` to `'foo'`.

This method works, but it doesn't support the `['square_bracket']` notation or any other javascript. I'm sure I could modify the method to do it later, but for now this works.